# how to find time difference between two times in MATLAB in custom format?

Tags: matlab, datetime

In MATLAB software, I want to calculate algorithm working time in custom format. It works, but how to customize it to show this format: year:month:day hour:minutes:seconds:miliseconds

It shows: '01 00, 0000  00:00:06 051', The result is not correct because of 01 on the first(month).

```
startTime=datetime('now');
%some working.....
endTime=datetime('now');
workedTime= datestr((endTime-startTime), 'mm dd, yyyy  HH:MM:SS FFF');
```

Comment: You want _year:month:day hour:minutes:seconds:miliseconds_ but you specify `'mm dd, yyyy  HH:MM:SS FFF'`. Can you clarify what format you want, and what problem you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin MATLAB function because duration in months is problematic (a month can be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days long).

You can use [between](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.between.html) function that returns **calendar** math differences.

Manual formatting is required, because calendar functions don't support your desired format.
First use [split](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calendarduration.split.html#targetText=Split%20Calendar%20Duration%20Array,-Open%20Live%20Script&targetText=When%20you%20request%20both%20the,12%20to%20the%20year%20value.) function to split the calendar duration to years, months, days, time, then use `sprintf` for manual formatting:

```
[y,m,d,t] = split(between(startTime, endTime), {'years','months','days','time'});
workedTime = sprintf('%02d %02d, %04d  %s', m, d, y, datestr(t, 'HH:MM:SS FFF'));
```